# Independence and Conditional Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence, density-function, gamma-distribution

Let us assume that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that $a_1 , a_2 , c_1 , c_2, d_1, d_2$ are positive real numbers. Let us define random variables

$$ \theta \sim \Gamma (a_1, b_1 ) , \ \lambda \sim \Gamma ( a_2 , b_2 ), \ k \sim U( \{ 1 ,\dots , n \} ) ,$$

where

$$ b_1 \sim \Gamma ( c_1 , d_1) \text{ and } b_2 \sim \Gamma (c_2 , d_2 ). $$

Let us also assume that $\theta , \lambda $ and $k$ are independent. Moreover, let $b_1$ and $b_2$ be independent. Next, we see that

$$ p_{\lambda, \theta, b_1 , b_2 , k} ( \alpha , \beta , \gamma , \omega , \tau ) = p_{\lambda , \theta , k| b_1 , b_2} (\alpha , \beta , \tau | \gamma , \omega ) \cdot p_{b_1, b_2} ( \gamma , \omega ). $$

Since $b_1$ and $b_2$ are independent, then $p_{b_1, b_2} ( \gamma , \omega ) = p_{b_1} ( \gamma) \cdot p_{b_2} ( \omega )$.  **My question is the following.** Does the independence of $\theta, \lambda$ and $k$ imply that

$$ p_{\lambda , \theta , k| b_1 , b_2} (\alpha , \beta , \tau | \gamma , \omega ) = p_{\lambda | b_1 , b_2} ( \alpha | \omega , \gamma) \cdot p_{\theta | b_1 , b_2} ( \beta | \gamma , \omega ) \cdot p_{k| b_1 ,b_2} ( \tau | \gamma ,\omega ).  $$

In other words, is it true that

$$ p_{\lambda, \theta, b_1 , b_2 , k} ( \alpha , \beta , \gamma , \omega , \tau ) = p_{\lambda | b_1 , b_2} ( \alpha | \omega , \gamma) \cdot p_{\theta | b_1 , b_2} ( \beta | \gamma , \omega ) \cdot p_{k| b_1 ,b_2} ( \tau | \gamma ,\omega ) \cdot p_{b_1} ( \gamma) \cdot p_{b_2} ( \omega ). $$

Symbol $p_{\textbf{X}}$ denotes the probability density function of a random vector $\textbf{X}$.

**Update**

To be more precise, the joint probability density function I had in mind is the following.

$$ \bigg( \frac{ \omega^{a_2} }{\Gamma (a_2)} \alpha^{a_2 -1} e^{- \alpha \omega} \bigg) \  \bigg( \frac{ \gamma^{a_1} }{\Gamma (a_1)} \beta^{a_1 -1} e^{- \beta \gamma} \bigg) \frac{1}{n} \  \bigg( \frac{ d_1^{c_1} }{\Gamma (c_1)} \gamma^{c_1 -1} e^{- \gamma d_1} \bigg) \  \bigg( \frac{ d_2^{c_2} }{\Gamma (c_2)} \omega^{c_2 -1} e^{- d_2 \omega} \bigg)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the language of graphical models you wrote a pdf corresponding to the following graph:

[image]

but the path $\theta \rightarrow b1 \rightarrow \lambda$ is not blocked, therefore $\theta$ and $\lambda$ are in general not independent (check the concept of $D-$separation).

In other words I think that the pdf you wrote is in general incompatible with even the independence between these two variables.

As a check, try to marginalize your pdf over $\lambda,b1,b2$ and try to write it as a product (you should not be able to do it).

**UPDATE:** To try to answer the comment, we can try to check what graphical models are compatible with the hypothesis. We start from the graphical form with only the arrows from b1 to $\theta$ and from b2 to $\lambda$. Now you start adding arrrows with the constraint that:

- you cannot have arrows between $b1$ and $b2$
- you cannot have arrows between $\theta,\lambda$ and $k$
- you should not generate unblocked paths between $b1$ and $b2$
- you should not generate unblocked paths between $\theta,\lambda$ and $k$

By making som trials it looks to me that you cannot insert any other arrow. This would lead to the distribution:

$$p \sim p(\theta|b1)p(\lambda|b2)p(b1)p(b2)p(k)$$

as the only one representable in the graphical model respecting the conditions. Problem is, I do not know/remember if all p.d.f. should be representable in a graphical model like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask how would you determine the joint probability density function of all parameters?

Comment: Right now not sure if I have some more thought on this will let you know.

Comment: I added some thoughts on this but not sure what we can conclude. Let's wait for other contributions ;)

Comment: Thank you for the thought you put in it. Wouldn't the distribution $p$ in the update be the same as the distribution I mentioned in the last line of my question?

Comment: Well no they are different. In my case theta lambda and k are independent (can you directly check it?) but not in your case

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't see it. Isn't the probability density function of $\theta$ given $b_1$ just the probability density function of Gamma distribution with parameters $a_1$ and $b_1$ in both cases?

Comment: In your case you have p(theta|b1,b2) not just p(theta|b1) so the interpretation I see of your formula is that after marginalizing on b2 you have the gamma distribution. In my case the link is more direct.

Comment: But the functional forms are totally different so they cannot be the same. I mean the expeessions are written differently so if you think they are the same you should prove that any expression written in the first form xan be appropriately rewritten in the second

Comment: I think I understand it. Thank you for your explanation. It seems that this computation is more difficult. I have added the explicit version of the joint probability density function in my question.

Comment: yes your updated formula is corresponding to the expression I suggested as the only one expressible in the graphical model and respecting your conditions

Comment: So now if every pdf is expressible in a graphical model than probably we would be 100% done

Comment: Would it be enough to say that $b_1$ does not affect $\lambda$, $b_2$ does not affect $\theta$ and that neither $b_1$ nor $b_2$ do not affect $k$; hence, we can drop them in my *incorrect* formula and turn it into the one that you pointed out?

Comment: Yes I think. But the point is that the fact that "b1 does not affect..." could not be assumptions but instead properties that are consequences of the original assumptions you stated, i.e. that "b1 must be independent of b2", that "theta, lambda and k" are independent, and the dependence you have of lambda from b2 and of theta from b1. If you start inserting any other interaction in a graphical model you end up violating these independence properties.

Comment: I am not 100% sure as I said that using graphica models alone proves the statement in full generality, but even if it is not enough for me everything points towards that direction, even if if other contributions come I would be glad :)